# Drop down does not appear in AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview, textwatcher

I'm working on a project in which I have to access data from SQLite3 database and show suggestions to user while typing. I have tried this with AutoCompleteTextView, but it's not working.
I'm working on this code:

```
ArrayList<String> sugestion = new ArrayList<String>();


public ViewGroup onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater , ViewGroup container , Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
myAutoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) group.findViewById(R.id.searchit);

searchDB = new searchAdapter(getActivity());

searchDB.getWritableDatabase();

myAutoComplete.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            suggestion = searchDB.getSuggestion(s.toString());

            Collections.sort(suggestion);

            String[] item = new String[suggestion.size()];

            item = suggestion.toArray(item);

            for(String word : item)
                System.out.println(word);

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {                

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

searchAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity() , android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, item);

        myAutoComplete.setAdapter(searchAdapter);

...
}
```

I have checked both the `ArrayList`(from database) and `String[]` array by printing it, they are having strings arranged.

My xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id = "@+id/group"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >


<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/searchit"
         android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Choose The Country" >

        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

.....
</RelativeLayout>
```

Dropdown for string suggestion does not appear while typing.  I have also tried with my own layout using textview instead of `android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line`. What am I missing here?. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: here is a link to another answer:
[auto complete text view drop down is not showing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41806707/4517450)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

You have set the adapter only in `onCreate()`. But you have populated value for your `item` array only inside `onTextChanged` in `TextWatcher`. so, try to set the `adapter` afetr populating your `item` array.

```
            myAutoComplete.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            suggestion = searchDB.getSuggestion(s.toString());

            Collections.sort(suggestion);

            String[] item = new String[suggestion.size()];

            item = suggestion.toArray(item);

            for(String word : item)
                System.out.println(word);

        searchAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity() , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);

        myAutoComplete.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
        myAutoComplete.setThreshold(1);

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {                

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: @KarthikSivam check my edit.. have not tested it.. but it might have any significant impact..

Comment: Your answer itself is working. Thank You and sorry I forgot to set threshold.

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
myAutoComplete.showDropDown()
```

Comment: That solved it. Wasted hours on it. Thanks mate !