# Suggestions not shown in AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have a AutoCompleteTextView in my layout. When a user enter "@" character in that i have to show them some suggestions. It normally names i get it from internet.

I am getting the names and i create an ArrayAdapter as shown below.

```
autoCtextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String lsatChar = s.toString().substring(s.length()-1,s.length()); 
            if(lsatChar.equals("@")) {
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DisplayQuestionDetails.this, 
                         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, namesLsist);
                autoCtextView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

But the suggestions are not shown. Am i doing anything wrong ? Please ask if need clarification on question

Comment: add threshold of autocompletetextview method to your code.

Comment: here is answer to this problem : [auto complete text view drop down is not showing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41806707/4517450)

Answer (score 6):

Do you miss `autoCtextView.setThreshold(1);` ?

(to start working from first character)

for example demo:

```
String[] strList={"a","aaa","aabb","b","bbc","cbb","c","cdd","caa","d","ddc","dda","e","eea","ebc","aec"};  
    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

        //Creating the instance of ArrayAdapter containing list
           ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>  
            (this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,strList);  

        //Getting the instance of AutoCompleteTextView  
           AutoCompleteTextView autoCtextView= (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);  
           autoCtextView.setThreshold(1);         //to start working from first character  
           autoCtextView.setAdapter(adapter);//set the adapter data to the AutoCompleteTextView  




}
```

Answer (score 3):

After declare autocompleteTextView than fill the first adapter.

like [Ref here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

```
public class CountriesActivity extends Activity {
 protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);
     setContentView(R.layout.countries);

     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
             android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
     AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
             findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
     textView.setAdapter(adapter);
 }

 private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
     "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
 };
```

}

Answer (score 3):

In my fragment layout, if I don't use the ems attribute (field size in number of "m"s), the suggestions will not be shown. When it is present, the suggestions are shown.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/enter_activities_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:completionThreshold="1"/>
```

Comment: that's my case. you saved me a lot of time, mate

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DisplayQuestionDetails.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, namesLsist);
autoCtextView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Before 
    autoCtextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {...

Answer (score 0):

I made custom AutoComplete Textbox with the help of this [blog](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/04/custom-autocomplete-for-android.html). It works when user types "@something", e.g."@f" then all the names which matches 'f' will come up.

CustomAutoComplete.java

```
public class CustomAutoComplete extends AutoCompleteTextView {
    private String previous = "";
    private String seperator = "@";

    public CustomAutoComplete(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.setThreshold(0);
    }

    public CustomAutoComplete(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setThreshold(0);
    }

    public CustomAutoComplete(final Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setThreshold(0);
    }

    /**
     * This method filters out the existing text till the separator
     * and launched the filtering process again
     */
    @Override
    protected void performFiltering(final CharSequence text, final int keyCode) {
        String filterText = text.toString().trim();
        previous = filterText.substring(0, filterText.lastIndexOf(getSeperator()) + 1);
        filterText = filterText.substring(filterText.lastIndexOf(getSeperator()) + 1);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(filterText)) {
            super.performFiltering(filterText, keyCode);
        }
    }

    /**
     * After a selection, capture the new value and append to the existing
     * text
     */
    @Override
    protected void replaceText(final CharSequence text) {
        super.replaceText(previous + text + getSeperator());
    }

    public String getSeperator() {
        return seperator;
    }

}
```

Layout file:

```
 <com.example.app.CustomAutoComplete
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    CustomAutoComplete autoCompleteTextView;
    String[] namesLsist = {"zivame","ziooo","zoooO","flipme","flipkart"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        autoCompleteTextView = (CustomAutoComplete) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, namesLsist);
        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Comment: @user965071 If you find something better than this answer, Please post it.